# Reading from CSV datetime by Pandas - problem with date&time format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I would like to set to the variable `x` following date:

```
x = dt.datetime.strptime(file_lines[0][0],'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

`file_lines[0][0]` is read by Panda from `.csv`.

I have following problem/error.
In `csv` I have date&time: 1/23/2019  2:04:00 PM, while once I set x variable, I get error:

```
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '1/23/2019 14:04' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: it has not seconds you can fill it as 0 or delete %S %p or just use try except method

Comment: your format is wrong - change it to `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`

Comment: @Datanovice  in the CSV file there is 00 seconds: 1/23/2019 2:04:00 PM so I can't remove it.

Comment: @Ευάγγελος Γρηγορόπουλος in the CSV file there is 00 seconds: 1/23/2019 2:04:00 PM so I can't remove it.

Comment: Ah got it, can you post five rows of your data I'll post a solution

Comment: @Datanovice: so following dates are parsed well, except of these ones with 00 seconds: 1/23/2019 2:04:00 PM

Comment: %S in the date format accepts seconds from 00 to 60 so I dont understand why I have this issue..